# Entity Framework - Is MS Going To Be Dropping Support For Database-First Approach

Tags: entity-framework

When I read posts about db-first vs. code first approaches, I get the impression that code-first is the rising star and superior to db-first so that db-fist is about to be deprecated in the future releases of Entity Framework.

I could not find an official statement from Microsoft but they seem to be endorsing code-first by things like Identity Framework etc. Would it be a mistake to start a new project using EF DB-first?

Answer (score 0):

You have EF 6 for the more traditional EF and EF 7 which became EF Core.
In my opinion you are better off focusing your effort on using EF independent from either approach.

Here's a link to an article written by EF Expert Julie Lerman.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890367.aspx